# unable to add line breaks. Why is it so?

Tags: php, line-breaks

The following script prints the strings from the `array` named `arr`. After an echo from `arr` I try to insert a line break using `\n` but I don't see it. Why is that ?

```
<?php
$arr = array("ghazal","shayari","silence","hayaat");
echo $arr[0];
echo $arr[1];
foreach($arr as $var) {
  echo $var;
  echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: good question! Ive had this problem before and got around it by using echo $var . "<br/>";

Comment: There are a thousand duplicates to this question, which is asked daily. Unfortunately they all have such rubbish titles I can't find them. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML treats all whitespace characters, in any number, identically.

That is, the following will all render as a single space in the browser:

```
echo "\n";
echo "\t";
echo "         ";
echo "  \n\n\n  ";
```

In order to render an actual *linkbreak* in HTML, you need to insert a `<br>` element into your document.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, the browser doesn't display `\n` linebreaks. If you view the source code, you will see them displayed. You can convert them to `<br>` using [the `nl2br` PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), or by changing your script from this:

```
<?php
$arr = array("ghazal","shayari","silence","hayaat");
echo $arr[0];
echo $arr[1];
foreach($arr as $var) {
  echo $var;
  echo "\n";
}
```

to this:

```
<?php
$arr = array("ghazal","shayari","silence","hayaat");
echo $arr[0];
echo $arr[1];
foreach($arr as $var) {
  echo $var;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

And if this doesn't work for you, you could always use the [`pre` HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/pre). The `pre` tag retains the `\n` linebreaks, and makes them visible.

If this helps, please mark this answer as correct by clicking the check next to this question.

Thanks. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for pointing that out. :) I edited my answer to reflect this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your PHP script is generating HTML that is viewed in a web browser. And, as we know, extraneous whitespace in HTML doesn't get rendered on screen.

Either generate plain text (`header("Content-type: text/plain")`) or output, instead of `'\n'`, something that renders a line break *in HTML* (e.g. `<br />`).

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
foreach($arr as $var) {
  echo $var;
  echo "<br />";
}
```

because in your HTML section `<br />` work for linebreak, your `\n` also works when you see the source code of HTML from browser's side that time it shows you the linebreak

Answer (score 0):

Because line breaks are rendered in HTML with `<br />`. Do this instead.

```
foreach($arr as $var) {
    echo $var, '<br />';
}
```

An alternative would be to wrap the output in `<pre></pre>`, which evaluates whitespace and linebreaks like what you're doing currently.

Comment: "HTML parses linebreaks as `<br />`" doesn't really work as English. HTML is a language, it doesn't *parse* anything. You might have said "New lines are represented in HTML as `<br />`".

Comment: And that's only conditionally true anyway.

Comment: I guess that was worded rather awkwardly - updated my answer.