# Php echo not printing newline even within double quotes or using PHP_EOL

Tags: php, echo

Here is a photo clip, I think it's pretty clear.
This is driving me crazy. I can't seem to get php to print a newline either on my localhost(using xampp) or on an online PHP interpreter.

[image]

Comment: Newlines have no meaning within HTML. That's why there are `<br>` tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to add line breaks. Why is it so?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392012/unable-to-add-line-breaks-why-is-it-so)

Comment: @mario However I took the example from http://us3.php.net/echo . I thought the expected outcome would be a line with linebreaks. Otherwise why would they include these examples in the official source?

Comment: They're referring to scripts running in the terminal / console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use HTML tag inside php, try this:

```
echo "dkljaks aalksja klajklsa<br/>";

echo "abc jjka kajkajs<br/>";
```

and see here for [br tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) and if you don't want to use HTML tag. try this: [nl2br() php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for line break.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<?php echo nl2br("This spans\r\nMultiple lines The new lines will be \r\noutput as well.",false); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `\r\n` instead of \n. Or you can also try `<br>` too.

\n will display a new line if you check the HTML source code in your browser.

Also http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=8021 might help you understand a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br>` for new line in html. new line is used in case of `console` output window.
You can see the references at [w3schools paragraph](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp)